# Django Queryset dynamic field value based on request.user

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset, django-managers

I have a webservice that returns list of links.

```
{
     [
         {"id":1,"href":"http://website.com","title":"Title1"},
         {"id":2,"href":"http://website.com","title":"Title2"},
         {"id":3,"href":"http://website.com","title":"Title1"}
     ]
}
```

Now I want to extend it to return also field `voted`, which will tell me if user has already voted for this link or not.

```
{
     [
         {"id":1,"href":"http://website.com","title":"Title1","voted": "True"},
         {"id":2,"href":"http://website.com","title":"Title2","voted": "False"},
         {"id":3,"href":"http://website.com","title":"Title1","voted": "True"},
     ]
}
```

**What is the best way to achive that?**

I've created model method `voted(self)`, but I don't think this is the best place for doing that, and still I don't have access to request.user in my model class.

```
 links\model.py ----------------------------------------

class Link(models.Model):
    href = models.URLField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=400)

def voted(self, request):
    vote = UserVotes.objects.get(link_id=self.link.id, user_id=request.user)
    if vote == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

--------------------------------------------------------

 votes\model.py ----------------------------------------

class UserVotes(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, blank=False)
    link = models.ForeignKey(Link, blank=False)
    vote = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=False)

    class Meta(object):
        unique_together = ('user', 'link')

--------------------------------------------------------

 link\serializers.py -----------------------------------

class LinkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    voted = serializers.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        model = Link

        fields = ('id', 'href', 'title','voted')
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'href', 'title', 'voted')

--------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can add a read-only `'voted'` [`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) to your serializer.**

This will add a key `voted` to the serialized representation of the object.

From the `SerializerMethodField` docs:

> It can be used to add any sort of data to the serialized
>   representation of your object.
>
> It should return whatever you want to be included in the serialized
>   representation of the object.

```
class LinkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    voted = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='has_user_voted') # add a 'voted' field

    class Meta:
        model = Link

        fields = ('id', 'href', 'title','voted')
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'href', 'title', 'voted')

    def has_user_voted(self, obj):
        user = self.context['request'].user # get the request object from context
        user_votes = UserVotes.objects.filter(user=user, link=obj)
        if user_votes:
            return True # return True if any user_votes object exists
        return False # otherwise return False
```